# Disable Buttons in a ListView's DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, button, datatemplate

So let's say I have a simple little WPF app that looks like this:

```
-------------------------------
Amount Left: 1,000
[Subtract 1]
[Subtract 5]
[Subtract 15]
[Subtract 30]
-------------------------------
```

"Amount Left:" and "1,000" are stand alone TextBlocks.
The "Subtract x" are all buttons, inside a ListView, inside a DataTemplate.  Each time a button is clicked, the amount of the button is subtracted from the 1,000.  All of that I have working.

Here's what I can't figure out.  When the Amount Left falls below 30, the last button needs to become disabled.  When the amount falls below 15, the second to last button becomes disabled. Etc and so on, until the Amount Left is Zero and all buttons are disabled.  I can not figure out how to disable the buttons.

This example I'm giving here is not *exactly* what I'm trying to do, but it's a greatly simplified example that will make this post a lot shorter and simpler. Here, in essence, is what I have now.

XAML:

```
<DockPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="Amount Left:" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="AmountLeft" Text="1,000.00" />
</DockPanel>
<DockPanel>
    <ListBox x:Name="AuthorListBox">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button x:Name="SubButtom" Content="{Binding SubtractAmount}" Click="clickSubtract" />
            <DataTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</DockPanel>
```

XAML.cs

```
    private void clickSubtract(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = sender as Button;
         Int32 SubtractAmount = ((Data.AppInformation)button.DataContext).SubtractAmount;  // This is the amount to be subtracted
        // logic to update the amount remaining.  This works.
        //  What I need to figure out is how to disable the buttons
    }
```

Comment: are you using MVVM? this can be done easily in the VM

Comment: Yes.  I am using MVVM.

Comment: I'll post an MVVM solution

Comment: dose your button now enabled/disabled ?

Comment: OMG! can you paste the XAML now.

Comment: post whole XAML as we have to find out where is the issue.

Comment: You've done so much already.  If you need or want to stop helping, i totally understand.  I just posted all of the code.  It's long.  And the example I gave in the OP was just a simplified example.  Thank you!!!

Comment: Are you sure its not hitting the breakpoint ? are you in debug mode ? what is your ShellViewModel doing ?

Comment: It is not hitting the break points.  Yep, I am in debug mode. I posted the ShellViewModel.  Thanks!

Comment: i dont see any problem till now. can you try clean the solution. rebuild, or create a small application to recreate the scenario.

Comment: A clean and re-build did not change anything.  This whole exercise is for a job interview process, and I have spent WAY to much time on it already. I would LOVE to get this working all the way, but I've done everything else on the todo list for this exercise.  I think I am going to send it back to them with this one requirement left undone.  If you want to share your email with me, I'll send you the entire solution and we can take one last stab it.  But I feel bad asking that, because you have already done so much.

Comment: Or maybe sharing emails is against SO's policy.  Maybe there is a better way to share the code.

Comment: add it to codeproject and share the link

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com  ?

Comment: Hey i was busy send me email to fnuabinmatthew@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

I would go ahead creating a Converter and bind the IsEnabled property of the button. pass the value and do the logic.

### Namespace

```
System.Windows.Data

System.Globalization
```

### CODE

```
 public class IsEnabledConverter : IValueConverter
 {
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, 
    object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    // Do the logic
  }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, 
    object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
    // Do the Logic
   }
}
```

### XAML

Add the resurce like this

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:IsEnabledConverter  x:Key="converter" />
</Window.Resources>

<Button x:Name="SubButtom" IsEnabled="{Binding Value, Converter=   {StaticResource  converter}}" Content="{Binding SubtractAmount}" Click="clickSubtract" />
```

You can learn about converters from below link

http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html

When you build the class with Converter all Xaml Errors will go off.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84690/discussion-on-answer-by-abin-mathew-disable-buttons-in-a-listviews-datatemplate).

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish using `MVVM`, by having an `IsEnabled` property for your Button `ViewModels`. With this approach, you will not need any 'code behind' as you currently have using a click event handler.

**Xaml:**

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="Amount Left:" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentAmount}" />
        </StackPanel>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Buttons}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Command="{Binding SubtractCommand}" Width="200" Height="75" x:Name="SubButtom" Content="{Binding SubtractAmount}"  IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**Xaml.cs:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

We want the main `ViewModel` that will have a list of `Button` `ViewModels`.

**ButtonViewModel.cs:**

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class ButtonViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool _isEnabled;
        private ViewModel _viewModel;

        public bool IsEnabled
        {
            get { return _isEnabled; }
            set
            {
                _isEnabled = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public int SubtractAmount { get; set; }

        public ICommand SubtractCommand { get; private set; }

        public ButtonViewModel(ViewModel viewModel)
        {
            _viewModel = viewModel;
            IsEnabled = true;

            SubtractCommand = new CommandHandler(() =>
            {
                _viewModel.CurrentAmount -= SubtractAmount;
            }, true);
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public class CommandHandler : ICommand
    {
        private readonly Action _action;
        private readonly bool _canExecute;

        public CommandHandler(Action action, bool canExecute)
        {
            _action = action;
            _canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return _canExecute;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _action();
        }
    }
}
```

and now the main `ViewModel`.

**ViewModel.cs:**

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int _currentAmount;

        public int CurrentAmount
        {
            get { return _currentAmount; }
            set
            {
                _currentAmount = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();

                if (Buttons != null)
                {
                    foreach (var button in Buttons)
                    {
                        if ((value - button.SubtractAmount) <= 0)
                        {
                            button.IsEnabled = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        public List<ButtonViewModel> Buttons { get; private set; }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            CurrentAmount = 1000;

            Buttons = new List<ButtonViewModel>
            {
                new ButtonViewModel(this)
                {
                    SubtractAmount = 1
                },
                new ButtonViewModel(this)
                {
                    SubtractAmount = 5
                },
                new ButtonViewModel(this)
                {
                    SubtractAmount = 15
                },
                new ButtonViewModel(this)
                {
                    SubtractAmount = 30
                }
            };
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, each Button `ViewModel` will decrement the `CurrentAmount` using a Command (the preferred method over a click event). Whenever the `CurrentAmount` is changed, some simple logic is done by the main `ViewModel` that will disable associated buttons.

This is tested and works. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Wow!  You did that incredibly fast.  Thank you. Now I'm going to try and figure out how to implement this into what I am already doing.

Comment: @CaseyCrookston no problem! maybe create a demo WPF application from scratch and copy/paste the code I provided. You can play around with that to help you understand a bit more how it works.

Comment: Yeah, I'll probably do that.  I was really hoping this would be a lot more simple.  All of this is for an exercise that a company sent me as part of a job application process.  They know that I have zero experience in WPF, but asked me to try anyway.  They sent me a WPF solution that was about 80% complete, and gave me the steps to finish the rest.  I've done all the tasks they asked me to do, except this one.  I need to try and figure out how to merge what you've given me into what I already have.

Comment: INotifyPropertyChanged is giving me trouble. I can't seem to get around this error: The type or namespace name 'INotifyPropertyChanging' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: Not sure what [CallerMemberName] is.  Help me out?

Comment: I think you just paste it on google will give you the answers, Include the namespace 'using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;'  'CallerMemberName' is used to get the property name or method name from where its called.

Comment: @CaseyCrookston did you get past it? what version of .NET are you using?

Comment: @d.moncada, I have been trying to implement your solution and Adin's in parallel.  I've coped all your code into an entirely separate solution.  I can't get yours to build. It gets hung up on [CallerMemberName].  Using .NET 4.5

Comment: ah ok.  Thanks Abin.  I thought the []'s meant i was supposed to replace [CallerMemberName] with something else.  So much of this is new to me.  Ok, I'm past that.  I'll try to run the app.

Comment: '[CallerMemberName]' is an attribute. keep it as shown in the solution.

Comment: Ok, the app works perfectly. Thank you!  Now I'll spend some time understanding it, and then getting it to work on my actual app.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option would be to use a command on the viewmodel instead of a click event handler:

```
public ICommand SubtractCommand = new DelegateCommand<int>(Subtract, i => i <= AmountLeft);

private void Subtract(int amount)
{
    AmountLeft = AmountLeft - amount;
}
```

XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="AuthorListBox">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
                <Button x:Name="SubButtom" Content="{Binding SubtractAmount}"
                        Command="{Binding SubtractCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding SubtractAmount}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Thanks Glen.  Couple of things.  Can you explain this: AncestorType=DataGrid?  Also, while I understand that "EnoughAvailable" is a bool, and I set it in the ViewModel, what I don't know how to do is grab the the amount from the given button and compare it.  And also, how do the method that makes the comparison get triggered when a button is clicked?

Comment: I didn't fully understand the question, I have changed the answer

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I already have the subtract part working. What I am having a HECK of a time getting to work is disabling the buttons when the amount is lower than their amount.

Comment: The second parameter of the DelegateCommand is a function that will enable/disabled the button depending on whether it returns true or false. It will update the IsEnabled automatically.

Comment: Will it do so for all buttons? Or just the one clicked?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84514/discussion-between-casey-crookston-and-glen-thomas).